# linear regression with log transform

Tags: regression, linear

I have a (time-series) data of 15 points:
(1,0.3555),(2,0.2739),(3,0.2379),(4,0.2254),(5,0.1826),(6,0.1715),(7,0.1549),(8,0.1314),(9,0.1452),(10,0.1148),(11,0.1051),(12,0.0996),(13,0.0941),(14,0.101),(15,0.0913).

[image]

This is actually a time-series data and I want to predict the day 30 value.
I try four regression models:

1. $y=\alpha x +\beta +\epsilon$
2. $y=\alpha \log x +\beta +\epsilon$
3. $\log y=\alpha x +\beta +\epsilon$
4. $\log y=\alpha \log x +\beta +\epsilon$

I used sklearn library of python and obtained the following r2 scores, respectively: 0.84726, 0.98784, 0.942937, 0.95827. Although r2 scores suggest the second model,  in predicting day-30 value the fourth model works better. My two questions are

1. Any metric, any method to determine the best working model
2. Any model suggestion other than linear regression.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: When you transform $y,$ the $R^2$ values are not comparable: it makes no sense to use them to evaluate your models.  As far as "any metric" goes, that's for you to determine based on what the consequences are of under- and over-prediction.

Comment: Did you correct your predictions in `log(y)` models for the fact that the $\mathbb{E}(\exp(y)) \neq \exp(\mathbb{E}(y))$ ? If you want unbiased estimates of your $Y$s, when estimating the model in `log`, you should not directly take the exponential of the prediction but also correct by an additional term